# How can I find contribution pages or membership pages where Profiles are used?

Tags: civimember, profile

I can see a list of all custom profiles
It says

Name: **Membership Details**
Type: **Membership::: : : : : : : : Teaching Member-EATA**
ID:   **13**
Used For:   **Standalone Form or Directory**

When I click on **[Find Members](https://www.example.com/civicrm/member/search?reset=1)** link from civicrm menu
i.e. https://www.example.com/civicrm/member/search?reset=1

In the image(of Find Members link given above) below I can see CTA Member,Teaching Member,Teaching member EATA as profile fields in member search link given above.
But I need to find where is this profile used in 
like a contribution page id 24 or something else
Is there anyway I can to find out ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to your db then you can look for the field in the civicrm_uf_field and look for the uf_group_id, then look in the civicrm_uf_group table to see which Profile it is used for, and then look in the civicrm_uf_join table to see where those uf_group_id are used. EG you may see that uf_group_id xx is used for civicrm_contribution_page that has entity_id yy